# Use Sql View in EF 6.0

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a CashFlowView:

```
    CREATE VIEW [dbo].[CashFlowView]
AS
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RateDate) AS ID
         , SUM(CASE WHEN C.CurrencyName = 'Br' THEN T.AmountMoney ELSE 0 END)  AS AmountBYR
         , SUM(CASE WHEN C.CurrencyName = 'Usd' THEN T.AmountMoney ELSE 0 END)  AS AmountUSD         
         , CR.RateDate AS [DATE]
FROM     Transactions AS T
         INNER JOIN Accounts AS A ON A.AccountID = T.CurrentAccountID
         INNER JOIN Currencies AS C ON C.CurrencyID = A.CurrencyID
         RIGHT OUTER JOIN CurrencyRates AS CR ON CR.RateDate = T.ExecutionDate
GROUP BY CR.RateDate
)
SELECT 
        ID
        , A.AmountBYR
        , (SELECT SUM(B.AmountBYR) FROM CTE B WHERE B.ID<=A.ID) AS BalanceBYR
        , A.AmountUSD
        , (SELECT SUM(B.AmountUSD) FROM CTE B WHERE B.ID<=A.ID) AS BalanceUSD
        , [Date]
FROM   CTE AS A
```

Then I've added the Entity:

```
public class CashFlowView
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public decimal AmountBYR { get; set; }
        public decimal BalanceBYR { get; set; }
        public decimal AmountUSD { get; set; }
        public decimal BalanceUSD { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
```

And, as I understand, I need to add this code to my context:

```
public DbSet<CashFlowView> CashFlowView { get; set; }
```

And now I wanna to use my View:

```
 IList<CashFlowView> listView;
            using (var _db = new EconomicAppContext())
            {
                listView = _db.CashFlowView.ToList();

            }
```

But listView is empty. How I may create correct mapping to View (maybe using migration) and use it?

Comment: Check the SQL statement that's generated. Run it in SSMS to check if if produces results.

Comment: Statement is ok. I've checked it. It's work fine.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you run the code and the SQL on the same database?

Comment: Yes. I've used this View in my DB in my work. Now I'am trying to use it in EF.http://screenshot.ru/ec06fed6ff494db0c9019798f567900f

Answer (score 0):

I did it. Try to combine this article 
http://www.paragon-inc.com/resources/blogs-posts/a-certain-point-of-view-part-1-ef-code-first
And use Entity Framework Power Tools to find needed result. And check connection. I've got problems with perfomance, so use dispose method carefully.